# VIM: In netrw window, how to return back to explore PWD?

Tags: vim

When I use `:Explore` to open netrw window and click `../` a few times, it will navigate to other path. Now, I want it back to :Explore my PWD path which is the path I launched the vim. What is the easiest way to achieve this? Thanks a lot.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Browsing within `:Explore` does not change the current working directory; you can call `:pwd` to verify. With the corresponding [`:help getcwd()`](https://vimhelp.appspot.com/eval.txt.html#getcwd%28%29) function, you can pass that to another `:Explore` command:

```
:exe 'Explore' getcwd()
```

If that's too much to type, you can define your own command:

```
:command! Oexplore exe 'Explore' getcwd()
```

Comment: Hi, I tried the command in vim. It works fine. But when I execute it in mvim, it doesn't work. Can you teach me how to do it in vim-in-gui? thanks a lot.

Comment: What doesn't work - wrong result from `getcwd()`, or `Explore` + path; do you get an error or just the wrong directory? And what is `mvim`, and which version is it?

Comment: Sorry, it works in `mvim`. My bad. I made a mistake. I was executing this command in the non-netrw window. Btw, `mvim` is a MacOS's version of gvim.